# Start a download link? JQuery or C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to run a download and then proceed with the code? How would i go about this?

This function is checking for when the file is fished downloading onto my sever, then i need to run a download to my client computer, witch is where i try the window.open("url").

```
function checkSpreadsheetProgress(taskId, filename) {
        var intervalId2 = setInterval(function () {
            $.post("SpreadSheetProgress", { id: taskId }, function (SpreadSheetProgress) {
                if (SpreadSheetProgress >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId2);
                    window.open("http://formvalue.co.za/download/" + filename + ".xlsx")
   //The line above is my attempt at running the download link but it did nothing?
   //The line below pushes me to my Downloadcompleate action result.
                    window.location.href = "downloadcomplete?filename=" + filename;
                } else {

                }
            });
        }, 100);
    }
```

I can download a file with C# but cant continue with the code behind my redirect method.

```
public ActionResult DownloadComplete(string filename)
{
    //return Redirect("http://formvalue.co.za/download/" + filename + ".xlsx");
    // The above line will download the file but then i cant return a view?
    return View();
}
```

Comment: why the quadruple quotes in `window.open("" ... "")`?

Comment: Sorry my bad its not like that in my code just a typo in my question, if edited, thanks for the spotting

Comment: Do you mean you literally want to wait until the download is finished before continuing? If so, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: The first argument to your success handler is the returned data, if I'm not wrong, which you are comparing to 100 for some reason. When the success handler is called, you already know request progress is at a 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the download status you must check this.
You can have some ideas based on this article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74654/File-Download-in-ASP-NET-and-Tracking-the-Status-o